# Appollo build pubblication failed

Tags: flutter

My Flutter Application when I do appollo build start and then pubblication, it gives me this error:

```
`[....................]
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 9 dependencies from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set.
In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to
`Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support
Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
----- Building IPA with Flutter -----

 Building with sound null safety 

Archiving com.xxx.app...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: (xxx)
Running pod install...                                           1,005ms
Running Xcode build...
Xcode archive done.                                          2.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/xs/ypw_ztps3mg5wt2mtfymvvb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.FOMFM6/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirWyfvCg/temporary
_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/A
rchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore.build/Script-D0AC535
1582A7D17DD6E0C3721EE0734.sh: line 2: /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore-xcframeworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99.
(in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99.
(in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase
"Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase
"Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99.
(in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99.
(in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99.
(in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/xs/ypw_ztps3mg5wt2mtfymvvb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.FOMFM6/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirWyfvCg/temporary
_xcresult_bundle


Encountered error while archiving for device.
----- Getting modified sources -----
IPA file not found
Build stop order received at 2023-05-02 12:29:46.263403+00:00`
```

But in the code I modified the podfile and corrected all the ios deployment target to 14 at least

It's my 15th build and I don't understand why, in the configuration I probate flutter runnas written in the official appollo documentation and there are no problems.

Answer (score 2):

can you try with the option --minimal-ios-version 14 when you run the build command? It will insert everything that is needed in the podfile and xcode project files, maybe you missed something when doing it manually

Comment: Even if it was the Build it didn't fail for this reason, the deployment target is under "warning", but it failed I think on this /Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates. noindex/A
rchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore.build/Script-D0AC535
1582A7D17DD6E0C3721EE0734.sh: line 2: /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore-xcframeworks.sh: Permission denied

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).